# can we update the value of relationship

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

I want to know whether we can update the parameter of relationship.
like food delivery, if I am having a relationship of a person and I am inheriting person and making a relationship of it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a runtime relationship of any transactions, participants and assets than you can use the Factory(Runtime API) method. Using Factory you can create instances of Resource. you can follow this [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/runtime-factory#newrelationship).

I hope you get your answer.